# how to access google datastore from an installed application on PC written in Python?

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, installed-applications

I have some entities added on datastore - made a little web app (in Python) to read and write from the datastore through endpoints. I am able to use the webapp through endpoints from javascript.
I want to access the web app from an installed application on PC. Is there a way to access endpoints from installed applications written in Python? How?

Is there any other way to access the datastore from PC installed applications written in Python?

Comment: Have a look at the remote_api we used it inside plone to author content and the publish to appengine. Plone used the remote_api to update/create content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the beauties of AppEngine's endpoints. You should use the Python Client Library for Google's APIs to communicate with your endpoints

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Then you'll construct a resource object to communicate with your api using  the *[apiclient.discovery.build](http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build)* function. For eg:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build


api_root = 'https://<APP_ID>.appspot.com/_ah/api'
api = 'api_name'
version = 'api_version'
discovery_url = '%s/discovery/v1/apis/%s/%s/rest' % (api_root, api, version)
service = build(api, version, discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url)
```

You can then perform operations at `service.<endpoint_method>` etc

A more complete example with authentication can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/access_from_python).

---

EDIT:

Or as @Zig recommends, directly use the Google Cloud API

```
pip install googledatastore
```

[Trivial example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/python/demos/trivial/adams.py)